# Output MySQL Query as HTML Table - enumerate fields

Tags: mysql, recordset, enumerate

i'd like to write a function for debugging purposes which will output a mysql query as html table including table fieldnames. how to enumerate the query's field names?

Comment: What do you mean 'enumerate'? Why would you do that?

Comment: which language ?? May be this help you http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm

Comment: Please provide sample output to clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad description, i was talking about php and could find out by myself:

```
foreach ($res as $result)
{
    foreach ($result as $col => $type)
    {
        echo "Column: ".$col." / ".$type;
    }
}
```

thanks